# How to create a legend for 3D bar

Tags: python, numpy, graph, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

Given `ax = plt.subplot()`:

`ax.bar()[0]` can be passed to `plt.legend()`.

However, `ax.bar3d()` returns `None`. How do I create legend for displayed bars?

UPDATE:

Passing legend="stuff" to `ax.bar3d()` and than calling `ax.legend()` raises

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:4368: UserWarning: No labeled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
warnings.warn("No labeled objects found. "
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use a [proxy artist](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) where legends are not supported.

This code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4)

elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+0.25, yedges[:-1]+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(elements)
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

ax.bar3d(xpos[:8], ypos[:8], zpos[:8], dx, dy, dz, color='b', zsort='average')
blue_proxy = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="b")
ax.bar3d(xpos[8:], ypos[8:], zpos[8:], dx, dy, dz, color='r', zsort='average')
red_proxy = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="r")
ax.legend([blue_proxy,red_proxy],['cars','bikes'])

plt.show()
```

produces this:[image]

Comment: With `matplotlib 3.7.1`: `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (8,) and arg 3 with shape (16,).`