# pyplot 3D bar legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to add legend to a 3d bar, but with no success.

I'm getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Patch3D' object has no attribute '_facecolor2d'
```

A minimal code for reproducing:
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for z in [10, 0]:
    xs = np.arange(20)
    ys = np.random.rand(20)
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', label=str(z))
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

How Can I add a legend to a 3d bar?

Comment: Always worth checking stack exchange for similar questions it's usually much quicker!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803015/how-to-create-a-legend-for-3d-bar-in-matplotlib

Comment: @Greg Good job with the duplicate!

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know how I miss it