# How to fill mplot3d bar plot depth? [Python 3.x]

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, mplot3d

There is an example for how to build a bar plot at the bottom of this question taken from the matplotlib site.

I cannot find a parameter to increase the depth of each bar. I want depth to give it a 3d look like [this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw9G7.png)

Is there a function parameter to change this that I'm not seeing, or will I need to use a different 3D bar plot function?

Below is the bar plot code from the first link in case someone can't see it:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
for c, z in zip(['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], [30, 20, 10, 0]):
    xs = np.arange(20)
    ys = np.random.rand(20)

    # You can provide either a single color or an array. To demonstrate this,
    # the first bar of each set will be colored cyan.
    cs = [c] * len(xs)
    cs[0] = 'c'
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs=z, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

I've found [this link to a solution](https://toeholds.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/3d-bar-histogram-in-python/) but this solution doesn't actually increase the depth. I'm hoping for a method to completely fill the depth if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803015/how-to-create-a-legend-for-3d-bar-in-matplotlib)? They use [bar3d()](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d), but the locations for each bar are manually created with meshgrid.

Comment: @PhillyAl isn't the linked answer the place from which you got the picture that you linked in your question!?

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's what I thought too; I can't figure out why that code doesn't do what PhillyAl is looking for. Maybe if the question is specifically _is there an easy depth parameter?_, I guess the answer is no.